# AngularJS : directive two way data binding not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller with following code snippet,

```
...
$scope.selected_contents = [];
$scope.$watch('selected_contents', function (sel_contents) {
  console.log(sel_contents, 'selected contents');
}, true);
...
```

a directive,

```
commonDirectives.directive('chkbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope : {
        item : '=item',
        selection_pool: '=selectionPool'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log('selected contents are', scope.selection_pool);
      // watch selection_pool
      scope.$watch('selection_pool', function (pool) {
        console.log(pool, scope.selection_pool, 'pool updated');
        if (_.contains(pool, scope.item)) {
          elem.prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
          elem.prop('checked', false);
        }
      });
      // toggle the selection of this component
      var toggle_selection = function () {
        if(_.indexOf(scope.selection_pool, scope.item) != -1) {
          scope.selection_pool = _.without(scope.selection_pool , scope.item);
        }
        else {
          scope.selection_pool.push(scope.item);
        }
      };
      elem.on('click', toggle_selection);
    }
  };
});
```

and a template which uses the directive,

```
<tr ng-repeat="content in contents">
      <td><input type="checkbox" selection_pool="selected_contents" item="content" chkbox></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is, changes in `selection_pool` in the directive is not reflected to `selected_contents` in the controller. What am i missing?

Update 1:

Following the suggestion from @mohamedrias I wrapped the changes in scope with `scope.$apply`. Doing so updates `selected_contents` in controller only while adding the content but not while removing it.

```
  ...
  // toggle the selection of this component
  var toggle_selection = function () {
    if(_.indexOf(scope.selection_pool, scope.item) != -1) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.selection_pool = _.without(scope.selection_pool , scope.item);
      });
    }
    else {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.selection_pool.push(scope.item);
      });
    }
  };
  ...
```

Comment: You must use `scope.$apply()` inside the click handler in directive

Comment: @mohamedrias could you explain it lil more? I wish to know why it is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for entire day, I ended up [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). If someone is having any trouble with `Angularjs` scope, I highly encourage to read it.

The proper solution in my case was to wrap `selected_contents` by an object. e.g.

```
$scope.selected = {};
$scope.selected.contents = [];
```

Then in the template replace `selcted_contents` with `selected.contents`.

But still what I don't understand is, `[]` or an Array is also an object. My earlier code should have worked according to the information I found in the wiki. If anyone could explain me why I would really appreciate it :).

Answer (score 2):

> Angular uses name-with-dashes for attribute names and camelCase for
>   the corresponding directive name

From [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace).

The variable should be changed from this `selection_pool`:

```
<input type="checkbox" selection_pool="selected_contents" item="content" chkbox>
```

to `selection-pool`:

```
<input type="checkbox" selection-pool="selected_contents" item="content" chkbox>
```

And this `selectionPool` into the directive:

```
scope : {
    item : '=item',
    selectionPool: '=selectionPool'
}
```

**EDIT**: Because the `selectionPool` is an array, you should use `$watchCollection`:

```
scope.$watchCollection('selectionPool', function (pool)
```

And when you add/remove values from the array in `toggle_selection` function, should be wrapped within the `$timeout` function:

```
$timeout(function () {
            if (_.indexOf(scope.selectionPool, scope.item) != -1) {
                scope.selectionPool = _.without(scope.selectionPool, scope.item);
             } else {
                 scope.selectionPool.push(scope.item);
             }
});
```

This is to assure that a `digest` cycle is going to be applied afterwards.

Here's the code working on a **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/0rvcguz0/3/

Comment: sorry still the same problem, the removal of content is still not reflected in the controller's `selected_contents`.

Comment: Sorry I understood something different , now I think I answered the question

Comment: $scope.$watchCollection did it for me. I was testing the behavior with $scope.$watch and it did not reflect the changes on the object